# Microsoft Access - Merging content with identical keys into a new table

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

In Microsoft Access, I would like to merge a specific column from tables having an identical key (=being duplicates) into a new table.

The source table would look like this

```
Key Content
Apple   X
Banana  B
Banana  D
Banana  E
Banana  G
Lemon   A
Lemon   X
Orange  A
```

I would like to create a new table where there is only one entry per key, each key having a field consisting of  all corresponding “content” fields accumulated into one field. Each “content” value should be delimited with something, example:

```
Apple   X
Banana  B<x>D<x>E<x>G
Lemon   A<x>X
Orange  A
```

I would prefer to have it like above, but it could also work if they are in different fields/columns like below:

```
Apple   X
Banana  B   D   E   G
Lemon   A   X
Orange  A
```

I would really appreciate help with this. When googling on this I have found a quit a few of third party add-ons (like this one http://www.tucows.com/preview/1586663/MS-Access-Join-Two-Tables-Software) that seems to be solving this, but surely this can be done with MS Access itself….or…?

Answer (score 1):

One version would be to use a UDF and this query:

```
SELECT Distinct Fruit.Key, 
    ConcatADO("SELECT Content FROM Fruit WHERE Key='" & [Key] & "'","<x>","<x>") 
       AS AllRows 
INTO NewFruit
FROM Fruit
```

User Defined Function (UDF)

```
Function ConcatADO(strSQL As String, strColDelim, strRowDelim)
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strList As String

   On Error GoTo Proc_Err

       If strSQL <> "" Then
           rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection
           strList = rs.GetString(, , strColDelim, strRowDelim)
           strList = Mid(strList, 1, Len(strList) - Len(strRowDelim))
       End If

       ConcatADO = strList

   Exit Function

Proc_Err:
       ConcatADO = "***" & UCase(Err.Description)
End Function
```

Working within the query design window, you can create a crosstab

```
TRANSFORM Min(Fruit.Content) AS MinOfContent
SELECT Fruit.Key
FROM Fruit
GROUP BY Fruit.Key
PIVOT Fruit.Content;
```

Which would return

```
Key     A   B   D   E   G   X
Apple                       X
Banana      B   D   E   G   
Lemon   A                   X
Orange  A
```

You could then save the crosstab and create a new query based on the cross tab. This query could be a Make Table query to get the new table, but as you can see, you have several columns.

If you have a predetermined number of possible rows for each key, there are other approaches.

Finally, you must ask yourself, is [de-normalizing](http://r937.com/relational.html) really the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to create the table with the two columns (Key, Content) then run the function below to copy the data into the new table. You'll have to replace "ExistingTableName" and "NewTableName" with your table names.

```
Sub CreateNewTable()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rsContent As Recordset
    Dim strContent As String
    'Select and loop through all keys
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Key FROM [ExistingTableName]")
    Do Until rs.EOF
      'Select all content records for this key and combine into a string
      Set rsContent = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Content FROM [ExistingTableName] WHERE Key = " & Chr(34) & Nz(rs!Key) & Chr(34))
      strContent = ""
      Do Until rsContent.EOF
        strContent = strContent & rsContent!Content & ","
        rsContent.MoveNext
      Loop
      If Len(strContent) > 0 Then
      strContent = Mid(strContent, 1, Len(strContent) - 1)
      End If
      CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [NewTableName] (Key, Content) VALUES (" & Chr(34) & Nz(rs!Key) & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & Nz(strContent) & Chr(34) & ")"
      rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rsContent = Nothing
End Sub
```

I don't think there is a way to do this without VBA.

Seeing as you are using a relational database you should consider using one table to store keys and another table to store content (one content per row/record), then link them up either by using a third table or by adding the 'key' as a foreign key in the content table. I would also always use an autonumber as the primary key in all MS Access tables, if not for every other reason this is a good idea, simply to avoid corruption and enable you to change a spelling mistake like 'aple' to 'apple' without breaking your relationships.

Comment: 'aple' to 'apple' without damaging the pie? :)

Comment: Sure, let me know if you would like more information about this.